# Embedding Font Awesome Icon inside of Java Script

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

Hi Im trying to embedded a font awesome icon inside of some JavaScript. The JavaScript (which I found online) creates automated Breadcrumbs on my site. Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function breadcrumbs(){
  sURL = new String;
  bits = new Object;
  var x = 0;
  var stop = 0;
  var output = "<a href=\"/\">home</a> &nbsp;>&nbsp; "; 
  sURL = location.href;
  sURL = sURL.slice(8,sURL.length); 
  chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
  sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length)
  while(!stop){
    chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
    if (chunkStart != -1){
      bits[x] = sURL.slice(0,chunkStart)
      sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length);
    }else{
      stop = 1;
    }
    x++;
  }
  for(var i in bits){
    output += "<a href=\"";
    for(y=1;y<x-i;y++){
      output += "../";
    }
    output += bits[i] + "/\">" + bits[i] + "</a> &nbsp;>&nbsp; ";
  }
  document.write(output + document.title);
}

<!--
breadcrumbs();
 -->
</script>
```

The code works great and does exactly what I want it to. But in place of the word "home" I would like to display a font Awesome Icon.

So where it says home here.

```
var output = "<a href=\"/\">home</a> &nbsp;>&nbsp; ";
```

I changed it to...

```
var output = "<a href=\"/\"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a> &nbsp;>&nbsp; ";
```

thinking it would display the font awesome icon instead of the word "home"
but it actually just breaks the code and nothing displays.

I'm new to JavaScript so I'm not sure why its not working. Please Help!

Comment: Change the string double quotation marks and turn them into single quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your output in single quot instead of double quot so it won't conflict with the double quot for `class="fa fa-home fa-lg"`. This will also allow you to remove the `\"` near the href.

```
var output = '<a href=""><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;>&nbsp;';
```

`\"` is used to escape a double quot inside a String surrounded by double quot. While it works perfectly, it's not as readable.
See [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) for more info on String usage.

Comment: Thanks.... It's kind of working, it's not breaking my script now but the icon is just displaying as a little square. Any ideas?

Comment: Ahhh no. It's just a square where ever I put it. Maybe I have to check the link to the css.

Comment: Okay... yea it was a bad link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use combination of `""` and `''` to make string concatenation easy and readible.

```
var output = "<a href='/'><i class='fa fa-home fa-lg'></i></a> &nbsp;>&nbsp; ";
```

Will work.